# mypy gives an error while importing submodule : Module has no attribute

Tags: python, django, mypy

When I am checking my modules through mypy it gives me this error:

> Module 'django.contrib.gis' has no attribute 'forms'

and I am importing forms like this:

```
from django.contrib.gis import forms
```

I know it is correct but mypy shows this error message.

I could import like this:
`from django.contrib import gis` and use `forms` as `gis.forms` but I do not want to.

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: it depends on where it going to importing django. like from system or virtual enviornment

Comment: my advise is to create one `virtualenvironment` and install django in it after activation of environment and run you project from that envornment.

Comment: I am doing all actions on docker

Comment: I know that using `from django.contrib import gis` is something you'd like to avoid but does that work? Also what version of mypy are you using? Your issue seems to be related to version 0.700 https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7182

Comment: @MoltenMuffins thank you. I will try to change version of mypy. Now I have mypy==0.761

Comment: @Liya I don't mean you should downgrade, I was simply wondering if you were using 0.700 which had this issue. In any case, could you try running mypy with this flag `--implicit-reexport` and see if this resolves the issue?

Comment: @MoltenMuffins now mypy showing me another +500 errors, but that error with import disappeared. Anyway, thank you

Comment: @Liya Alright, I've made the comment an answer. If using the `--implicit-reexport` flag really was the solution to your issue, please accept my answer so others with the same issue would be able to know that this worked for you. However I have a feeling that it probably isn't the root cause of the problems you're facing. Is there anything in common for the +500 errors you're getting now?

Comment: This still doesn't work for version 0.990

Answer (score 15):

It appears that your problem is similar to this issue raised in `mypy`'s github repo:

#### [Module X has no attribute Y, since version 0.700 (works fine with 0.670)](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7182)

wherein the author of the issue originally ran `mypy` with the following line

`RUN mypy --strict ./mypackage/tests.py`

and solved the problem by running `mypy` by adding on the `--implicit-reexport` flag as follows:

`RUN mypy --strict --implicit-reexport ./mypackage/tests.py`

Comment: seems like the flag is undocumented, but still works as of mypy 0.971

Comment: The command line options work the same way as the [configuration file options](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#inverting-option-values).  Booleans can be negated by adding/removing `no-` or by swapping `allow-` with `disallow-`.  So `--implicit-export` and `--no-implicit-export` are recognized, for example.